# MySQL double result when querying

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm getting a double result when I execute my query. First I was getting like 3x the data so I did change the query a bit and now it is double (2x) for every record in my table.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    (q.totalExcl) AS totalExcl
FROM
    ex.ps_orders o LEFT JOIN
    ex.ps_oxo_quotation q ON o.id_order = q.idOrder LEFT JOIN
    ex.ps_sv_employee_meta m ON q.idEmployee = m.id_employee 
WHERE
    idEmployee = 6
        AND q.date_add >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
        AND o.current_state IN (3, 4, 5, 9, 13, 15, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 121);
```

And my table looks like this

```
╔══════════════╦
║  totalExcl   ║
╠══════════════╬
║  500.0000000 ║
║  500.0000000 ║
║  150.0000000 ║
║  150.0000000 ║
║  23.0000000  ║
║  23.0000000  ║
╚══════════════╩
```

What I want is like this one:

```
╔══════════════╦
║  totalExcl   ║
╠══════════════╬
║  500.0000000 ║
║  150.0000000 ║
║  23.0000000  ║
╚══════════════╩
```

It does work when I delete this line from my query but I need this line later (I need to get some tables from this table called `expoled.ps_sv_employee_meta`  later):

```
LEFT JOIN
    expoled.ps_sv_employee_meta m ON q.idEmployee = m.id_employee
```

---

I found the solution changed this line `SUM(q.totalExcl)`to `SUM(q.totalExcl /2)`

Comment: you need a group by, but as is it's hard to say on what, as you've provided not too much of your needs. I'd say on the orders id field?

Comment: When I do GROUP BY 'q.totalExcl' it still gives me dubbel results

Comment: The data appears to be duplicated because multiple records from another table matches each record in ex.ps_oxo_quotation table. You can use distinct or group by to eliminate the duplication in the short time, but if you need to add other fields later, then these solution will not last.

Comment: I'm happy for you that you found what was causing it, but in the query _you provided_, **there was no `SUM(q.totalExcl)`!**

Comment: I had to add that line

Answer (score 2):

`SUM(.../2)` *assumes* that there are always exactly 2.  That is unsafe.

It seems strange to fetch a column without some indication of what case it is -- maybe the `current_state`, maybe the `date_add`.  I suggest you add both of those to the `SELECT` list (and without any `GROUP BY` or `SUM`).  This will give you a clue as to why the rows are doubled up.

`SELECT DISTINCT ...` would get rid of the doubling, but it might mess up in a different way -- suppose that two rows legitimately have value `23`.

Change both `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN`.